# Trouble creating a check program in automake

Tags: automake

I'm trying to learn automake (Autotools by John Calcotte) and am stumped on creating a check program to test my C++ library. A partial listing of the program is given below. The example in the text shows creation of a test program using a shell script testing the output of the test program. I have a program, linked to the library, which when executed tests the library functionality. Do I have to create the test program using noinst and then execute using a shell script? Any scripting examples or references to examples would help.

Thanks

```
The errors are:

    src/Makefile.am:27: warning: variable 'check_SOURCES' is defined but no program or
    src/Makefile.am:27: library has 'check' as canonical name (possible typo)


# Create a library
    lib_LIBRARIES      = libslip.a
    libslip_a_SOURCES  = $(sources) $(privateHeaders)


# Header files for testing SLIP

    testHead=TestGlobal.h TestHeader.hp TestIO.h TestMisc.h TestOperators.h TestReader.h TestReplace.h TestSequencer.h TestUtilities.h


# Source files for testing SLIP

    testCPP=Test.cpp TestGlobal.cpp TestHeader.cpp TestIO.cpp TestMisc.cpp  TestOperators.cpp TestReader.cpp TestReplace.cpp TestSequencer.cpp  TestUtilities.cpp


# Test Program
    check_PROGRAMS   = Test
    check_SOURCES    = $(testHead) $(testCPP)
    TESTS            = $(check_PROGRAMS)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a slight misunderstanding: `check_PROGRAMS = Test` is fine, but just as with the `libslip` sources, `Test` is used as a prefix:

```
Test_SOURCES = TestGlobal.h TestHeader.hp TestIO.h TestMisc.h TestOperators.h \
        TestReader.h TestReplace.h TestSequencer.h TestUtilities.h Test.cpp \
        TestGlobal.cpp TestHeader.cpp TestIO.cpp TestMisc.cpp TestOperators.cpp \
        TestReader.cpp TestReplace.cpp TestSequencer.cpp TestUtilities.cpp
```

In this case, it's fine to include headers in `SOURCES`. Each new line after the line break should start with a TAB character. Of course, you can continue using `$(testHead)` and `$(testCPP)` variables if you prefer. To link with `libslip`:

```
Test_LDADD = libslip.a
```

or simply:

```
LDADD = libslip.a
```

if linking `libslip` with all programs in this Makefile. `check_PROGRAMS` targets are implicitly `noinst`.

You might also find the [Autotools Mythbuster](https://autotools.io/index.html) a useful resource.

Comment: Modified src/Makefile.am is:

# Testing SLIP
testdir            = ./test

check_PROGRAMS      = test
test_SOURCES       = $(testCPP) $(testHead)
test_LDADD         = libslip.a
TESTS              = $(check_PROGRAMS)

CLEANFILES         = $(testdir)

The compile is successful but linking is not done. 

        g++: warning: Test.o: linker input file unused because linking not
done

for each source file. .

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez - maybe you could edit / format your question. It would be easier to understand than a wall of text with no markup.

Comment: I've gotten beyond the initial point. I'm now trying to link my test results to *any one of) the automake frameworks and to clean my files properly (using CLEANFILES). My test program is executed and works correctly. My test.trs file is overwritten by the framework and my test.log file is not copied to test-results. I'm reading the automake manual (again) to see if it makes sense and I have read John Calcote's book - no help. I've looked a Autotools Mythbusters but nothing strikes me as addressing the automake testing framework. Help is nice.